# Select element if we don't know his name

Tags: jquery

How can apply this code :

```
$( "#prev ~ div" ).css( "border", "3px groove blue" );
```

i can't select `#prev` directly because in my code i have just `var myDiv = $(this).parent();`

How can i selects all sibling elements that **follow** after the `myDiv` element ?

Something like that will work `$( myDiv "~ div" ).css( "border", "3px groove blue" );` ?

Comment: Neither your jsfiddle nor the url you are trying to iframe in it are working so it's hard to see what you're talking about in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use `siblings()` method to get all the siblings

```
var siblingsElements = myDiv.siblings();
```

You can also use the selector as you are using like this (for selecting the next siblings only)

```
$('#' + myDiv.attr('id') + "~ div").css( "border", "3px groove blue" );
```

and I am assuming that `myDiv` has an `id` attribute.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95DwK/)

Comment: i want select just sibling elements that **follow** after the myDiv element ?

Comment: @Youssef look at the selector that I am using and let me know if it helped.

Comment: it doesn't work :( i think we can't combine thins like `$(myDiv.attr('id') + "~ div")` we have to find a method and `nextAll()` do the work :)

Comment: @Youssef put '#' as well before the myDiv like this `$('#' + myDiv.attr('id') + "~ div")`

Comment: but if we don't know the `id` i think it will be impossible right ?

Comment: yes in that case this method won't work then you need to use the `.nextAll()` method

Answer (score 3):

If you want elements after that elmenet you can do this:

```
myDiv.nextAll(".yourelement")
```

More info on [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

Comment: thanks @Niels it's work but i want to know if something like  `$( myDiv "~ div" ).css( "border", "3px groove blue" );` that will work

Comment: You can create your own selector which can do that. More info here http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html

Comment: no the answer fit my needs but i'm just looking for other solution, read again my topic i want a way to work not just a jquery function if we don't know function and we have to deal just with selector.